# Excel: Sums to be Zero

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, php

[image: Excel]

What formula to use so that I can get every possibility for sum 0.

[image: Result]

I can achieve it in PHP how in excel?

[PHP execution](https://3v4l.org/rY1SQ).

Comment: The easiest should Goal Seek or Solver Commands,, but no need to think for other options since `SUM` of `B2:B6` returns `0`.

Comment: This task can be solved using VBA code only - formulas or Solver can give only one solution, not all. So you can simply convert PHP to VBA.

Comment: You should be able to do this in excel using formulas only. Think about each row in excel as an individual "for each" loop (in your PHP program). construct your array of inputs and then simply use the `=SUMPRODUCT()` formula. I leave the details for you to figure out.

Comment: So, how can we convert PHP to VBA? @Akina any small code related to this.